# I want to load 2nd div first and 1st div second

Tags: php, wordpress

`<div class="a">hello</div> 
<div class="b">bye</div>`

I have a one page website and I want a div to be loaded first and then the second one and... Can I do this just with html and css? Or it needs JavaScript or...

Comment: Why can't you just change their order in HTML?

Comment: You need to implement JavaScript or jQuery code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with something like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".b").delay(2000).fadeIn(500); //class b is on delay
});
```

Can't done with only **HTML** and **CSS**. Need to involve **JavaScript** or **jQuery** code too.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with Javascript:

1. Change your Body to `<body onload="onloadFunction()">`
2. Add `style="display: none;"` to your div Elements
3. Add following script:

   ```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
       function onloadFunction(){
           document.getElementsByClassName("a").style.display = "true";
           document.getElementsByClassName("b").style.display = "true";
       } 
   </script>
   ```

and change the order of the document. lines to which order you want to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need javascript and I suggest jquery(javascript library).
More info at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

And here is working example(just run with browser and click button):

```
<div class="a" style="display: none;">hello</div> 
<div class="b" style="display: none;">bye</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a').show();
    setTimeout(function(){$('.b').show()}, 2000);
});
</script>
```